# If the folder name has a space character, the zipper will not be done. How to ignore the space character in String?

Tags: visual-studio, zip, getdirectories

In this code, if the folder name has a space character, the zipper will not be done. How to ignore the space character in str. But it's not working.

```vbnet
        Dim pinfo As New ProcessStartInfo()

        pinfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"

        Dim s As String = txtCode.Text

        Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("D:\نهایی\" & s)

        For Each dirItem As DirectoryInfo In dir.GetDirectories

            Dim str As String = dirItem.ToString()

            Dim dis As String = "D:\نهایی\" & s & "\" & str & ".rar"

            Dim src As String = " D:\نهایی\" & s & "\" & str

            pinfo.Arguments = "a -cpF " & dis & src

            Dim p As Process = Process.Start(pinfo)

            p.WaitForExit()

        Next
```

Comment: Make sure you put literal quotation marks around your string.